# Accessing Treeview from a dllplugin. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, treeview

I am writing a plugin for an app that needs to access the client's treeview.  What is the best way to do this?  Would it simply be the case of passing the treeview reference through to the dll?

The plugin will need to update the treeview based on data being uploaded to a database from the plugin.  When this data is uploaded, additional nodes will require to be added to the treeview.  I have methods that fulfil this functionality within the client, however I need this to be achieved through the dll.

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking for the "best" way without giving *any* details that would help anybody help you by giving the best advice.  This is a very poor and lazy question.

Comment: Sorry Hans.  I will elaborate more in my post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way to achieve this is changing the architecture a bit.
Your component that monitors database should declare an event i.e: RecordsAdded. The treeview should add its own handler to that event, which would update its content as desired.
Possibly there should be more tiers, but that is just an idea, not a complete solution.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I didn't really think of this, as the database code has already been written and is being called by my add-in.  I do have access to the database code, so I can simply add an event there that is handled by the client and updated as necessary.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution (which I actually used myself) is to do like IIS 7 do and let the user register "hierarchy providers" that manipulate the nodes in the tree.

You can read more about the IIS 7 tree manipulation and get some inspiration here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/08/12/extendingtreeview.aspx